# Missing handlebars helper error when using helper in partials. express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have registered helpers using `express-handlebars` like this:

```
const { create } = require("express-handlebars");
//Sets our app to use the handlebars engine
const hbs = create({
  helpers: require("./config/handlebars-helpers"),
});
app.engine("handlebars", hbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.set("views", "./views");
```

And these are my helpers

```
// handlebar-helbers

const Handlebars = require("handlebars");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  whichPartial(ui_type, code_name, data) {
    console.log(ui_type, code_name);
    let partial = fs
      .readFileSync(
        path.join(
          __dirname,
          `../../views/partials/${ui_type}/${code_name}/index.handlebars`
        )
      )
      .toString();
    console.log(partial);
    return Handlebars.compile(partial)({
      data: data
        ? {
            ...data,
          }
        : {},
    });
  },
  if_eq(a, b, opts) {
    if (a === b) {
      return opts.fn(this);
    } else {
      return opts.inverse(this);
    }
  },
  times(n, block) {
    var accum = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) accum += block.fn(i);
    return accum;
  },
};
```

But whenever I use a helper inside a partial it says the helper is missing.
But it works inside main handlebars files.

I am not able to figure out the reason. If someone would help me it would be great.

Comment: The partials do not have access to the helpers because the Handlebars instance on which you are calling `Handlebars.compile(partial)` within the `whichPartial` helper does not have the helpers registered to it. Is there a good reason you are using this design choice of calling `Handlebars.compile` instead of using the engine created for the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Handlebars helpers you are exporting from `./config/handlebars-helpers` are made available to your app's Handlebars engine when you register them in your `hbs = create` call.

However, the partials that you return from your `whichPartial` helper are compiled with a different Handlebars instance - one that has no helpers registered with it.

I would advise against creating separate Handlebars instances in this manner. express-handlebars will already compile all of the partials in your `views/partials` directory.

It seems the purpose of your `whichPartial` helper is to allow the calling code to specify the directory parts. You can still achieve this, but without the compilation, by simply returning the filepath string from the `whichPartial` helper. It becomes:

```
whichPartial(ui_type, code_name) {
  return `${ui_type}/${code_name}/index`;
},
```

And the template code to call it is:

```
{{> (whichPartial "your_ui_type" "your_code_name")}}
```

Comment: I figured that out and fixed it. You have provided me with a better solution for `whichPartial`. Thanks!